# Strange and unknown error while compiling QT code

Tags: qt

[image]I don't know why I am getting error or these statements. The same code works fine when I compile it for x86_64 system but when I changed target to Beaglebone Black and switched to angstrom tool chain the QTcreator started giving error in these lines.

```
//connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [=]{
ui->textBrowser->append(process->readAllStandardError());
});
connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=]{
ui->textBrowser->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
});
```

Errors are for the expression "[=]". Infact I don't know why this error is coming. Could this be related to version, bcoz BBB is have qt4-embedded. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that you added CONFIG += c++14 ?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax is for qt5 only

Comment: I am using CONFIG += c++11

Comment: @Learner Sorry for confusing, c++11 should work fine.

Comment: @user3528438 So it means that I can't use the same for qt4-embedded ?

Comment: Possibly not. But the qt4 syntax still works with qt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for connecting signal to c++11 lambda has been added to Qt 5. Since previous version (Qt4) doesn't define the right signature for `connect()`, you can't use it. You should transform your code to match the correct syntax:

```
connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), receiver, SLOT(yourCustomSlot()) );
```

With a slot declared as follow:

```
class MyReceiverClass {

slots:
    void yourCustomSlot() {
        ui->textBrowser->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
    }
};
```

Comment: can you help me a littile bit more? Adding a custom slot not working for me, getting errors if i add the slots in mainwindow.h
I have replaced my original connect line in mainwindow.cpp with the one which you suggested and added class MyReceiverClass in mainwindow.h . Code doesn't gets compile.

Comment: You should write a new question